# functions does not run

Tags: jquery, document, fadein

I want to know what my problem is in this code :

I want that my div fade in

but id don't know why it doesn't run as good as i want. I hope you help me.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title> my site </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document) .ready (function() {
      $("#frame").fadeIn(3000);
    });

    </script>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
    * {margin:0 auto; padding:0;}
    body {background:#333;}
    #myframe {width:500px; height:300px; background:#006699;font:50px tahoma;
    text-align:center; color:#fff; line-height:100px;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="myframe">
         My site . 
    <br />
    THIS IS MY SITE.
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `but id don't know why it doesn't run as good as i want.` Can you please quantify ***how*** good you want it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS:

```
#myframe{
    ...
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document) .ready (function() {
    $("#myframe").fadeIn(3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Typo.

```
$(document) .ready (function() {
   $("#myFrame").fadeIn(3000);
});
```

there is no element with `frame` as its id. You've got only `myFrame` as Id. So the above should work.

Answer (score 0):

You declare myframe but the javascript is lookign for id frame

```
<div id="frame">
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery FadeIn will only show your div if it has already Given Display None

http://api.jquery.com/fadein/ for complete Doc.

you have to change your code. you have Given wrong id **frame** change it to **myframe**.

```
$(document) .ready (function() {
      $("#myframe").fadeIn(3000);
    });
```

and added style to `#myframe{display:none;}`

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLgb5/)